# Removing Tabulation from Firebird

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm trying, but I can not seem to get a tab at the end of a varchar in Firebird. Does anyone know how to do it?

To be more specific:

```
Select guia, convenio, nome, trim (matricula) from table where guia = '142'
Group by guia, convenio, nome, trim (matricula)
```

The result

```
142 | 1 | Name of patient | 111222
142 | 1 | Name of patient | 111222
```

However, if I remove the enrollment field, which is a varchar(40) which is with the tabs:

```
Select guia, convenio, nome, matricula from table where guia = '142'
Group by guia, convenio, nome
```

The result is:

```
142 | 1 | nome do paciente
```

And as I discovered that the problem was enrollment:

With the help of this function: `char_length(matricula)`

```
Select guia, convenio, nome, matricula, Char_Length(matricula) from table where guia = '142'
Group by guia, convenio, nome, matricula
```

The result:

```
142 | 1 | nome do paciente | 111222 | 6
142 | 1 | nome do paciente | 111222 | 10
```

Comment: Why do you do a GROUP BY when you have no aggregate functions (e.g. MAX, SUM, COUNT)? Also the general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what the problem is. Can you add more information. Because you say _"I can not seem to get a tab at the end of a varchar"_, however the rest of your description seems to indicate the opposite (that is: you want to remove the tab character). Note that the real solution would be to prevent those characters to get in the database in the first place.

Comment: That's exactly what I told my boss ... but he wants it done like this ... I need to re-record the field tab, so the group by see the same registration and be one line. But with the tab, the character size differs from one line to another ....

Comment: What do you mean with _"I need to re-record the field tab"_?

Comment: I need to remove the tab at the end of the matricula field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the tabs at the end of a value, you have several options:

- Use [`TRIM`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-trim) with an explicit string

  ```
   trim(trailing ascii_char(9) from theColumn)
  ```

  `9` is the tab character. This solution assumes that there is no combination of spaces and tabs at the end.
- To address the deficiency of the previous solution, use [`REPLACE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-replace) to replace tab with a space and then trim:

  ```
    trim(trailing from replace(theColumn, ascii_char(9), ' '))
  ```

However the best solution would be to sanitize your data by updating it, and changing your application so that these trailing tabs (and spaces) don't end up in the database. Alternatively you could add a trigger that does this for you.